# Where does RPL come from?

Tags: assembly, x86, privileges, osdev, memory-segmentation

I am a little confused I read from many different sites but it is not clear to me:

> Every segment register has a visible part and an inivisible
>   part. The visible part is referred to as the segment selector
>   and there are direct instructions to load the segment selector.
>
> Requester Privilege Level(RPL): this field identifies the privilegel
>   level to provide protected acces to data.

Ok so, I understand that I can use instructions in assembly, for example, to load a selector, but I cant modify the RPL right? where does it come from? How does the CPU choose it? Thanks

Comment: If you want to be a hacker, you need to learn where to find information like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The RPL is actually just the lowest 2 bits of the segment selector, so you can load any priviledge level you want into it (0-3), but if the requested level is higher (lower numerically) than the DPL of the corresponding segment, you'll get a GP fault.  This allows a program to easily access a segment with less priviledge than the OS has granted it, if that is relevant for memory mapped I/O or whatever.

Comment: Then why is it called invisible part? Who cant see it? Thanks

Comment: The RPL is part of the visible part.  The invisible part holds info from the segment descriptor and is loaded automatically from the descriptor table any time the segment register is modified.  It includes the DPL among other things.

Comment: Hey Chris, you have it backwards:  You'll get a #GP accessing a segment if the segment selector has an RPL which is *greater numerically* than the segment's DPL.  (Lower numbers == higher privilege)